# "Chance of [gerund]" vs. "chance at [gerund]"

Tags: meaning, word-choice, prepositions

Which is correct?

> - If you tell me the cause, I will have a better chance **at** fixing the problem.
> - If you tell me the cause, I will have a better chance **of** fixing the problem.

A quick Google search for the two phrases returns a nearly equal number of results. So, perhaps both are correct.

However, there are some scenarios where it seems "chance of" is the only correct option. For example,

> The chances **of** dying in an airplane crash are nearly 100%.

Using "*chances **at** dying*" doesn't seem right in the above statement.

Are there any general usage guidelines for this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Chance of* and *chance at* mean different things. The first refers to likelihood, the second to opportunity.